# How to get Sum of Column, Where another column has Count = 1

Tags: sql, select, group-by, distinct

Sample Data:

```
+===========================================================================+
|NoBoxes | Carrier | ProcessDateTime | Errored | Voided | TrackingNumber    |
+===========================================================================+
|  2     |  UPS    | 5/22/2013 8:14  |    0    |    0   | 1Z1234567891234567|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        |  UPS    |                 |    0    |    1   | 1Z1234567891234567|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+    
|  5     |  UPS    | 5/22/2013 8:22  |    1    |    0   |                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  7     |  UPS    | 5/22/2013 8:14  |    0    |    0   | 1Z9876543210987654|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1     |  UPS    | 5/22/2013 8:22  |    0    |    0   | 1Z1472583691472583|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1     |  FedEx  | 5/22/2013 8:14  |    0    |    0   | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  8     |  FedEx  | 5/22/2013 8:22  |    0    |    0   | yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  3     |  USPS   | 5/22/2013 8:14  |    0    |    0   | zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  4     |  USPS   | 5/22/2013 8:22  |    0    |    0   | aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  7     |  UPS    | 5/22/2013 8:14  |    0    |    0   | 1Z9638527411012396|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  9     |  UPS    | 5/22/2013 8:22  |    0    |    0   | 1Z4561591981655445|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now with a table like this, how can I get the sum of `NoBoxes` Where `Carrier` = UPS, `ProcessDateTime` = Today, `Errored` = 0, and `TrackingNumber` Having Count = 1?

The duplicate Tracking Numbers represent a shipment that was voided. 
I don't want to sum `Errored` shipments as those didn't ship.

I have tried about 10 different statements and nothing can seem to get me where I need to be.

The issue I ***Believe*** is that the voided rows do not contain a `ProcessDateTime`.

So when I use something like:

```
SELECT Sum(NoBoxes)
FROM Info
WHERE (Carrier='UPS') AND (ProcessDateTime>{ts '2013-05-23 00:00:00'} And 
ProcessDateTime<{ts '2013-05-24 00:00:00'}) AND (Errored=0)
GROUP BY TrackingNumber
HAVING (Count(*)=1)
```

It still returns `TrackingNumber` that have been voided because the query doesn't contain any rows with null `ProcessDateTime`

so then I tried:

```
SELECT Sum(NoBoxes), ProcessDateTime
FROM Info
WHERE ((Carrier='UPS') AND (Errored=0))
OR
((Carrier='UPS') AND (ProcessDateTime Is Null) AND (Errored=0))
GROUP BY ProcessDateTime, TrackingNumber
HAVING (Count(*)=1)
```

But this still doesn't do the job it just returns everything.

Also tried `HAVING (Count(TrackingNumber)=1)` but didn't seem that did anything.

I just can't figure out how to get rid of all duplicate tracking numbers, then return the sum of all `UPS` with a `ProcessDateTime` value within criteria. Because it seems the only way to get rid of the duplicates is to not use `ProcessDateTime` at all, but then I have no way of telling what the `ProcessDateTime` is, and I need to know in order to filter for specific date.

I kind of understand that I will probably have to do something like:

```
(Select TrackingNumber 
 From Info 
 Where Carrier = 'UPS' And Errored = 0
 Group By TrackingNumber HAVING Count(*) = 1) As A
```

Then do something along the lines of:

```
Select  Sum(NoBoxes) As Total
From Info
Join A On Info.TrackingNumber = A.TrackingNumber
Where Info.ProcessDateTime>{ts '2013-05-23 00:00:00'} And 
      Info.ProcessDateTime<{ts '2013-05-24 00:00:00'}
```

But I am simply not knowledgeable about this to get all the right order and syntax correct on such a Query.

Given the table provided I would like a single Row returned with a single Column with the Value of `24`

Comment: Can you show the results that you want from the sample data?

Comment: @GordonLinoff You may reference the second to last line of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading over my own question I realized how to do this using exactly the same sub queries I though I should, this worked exactly as I hoped.

```
Select  Sum(NoBoxes) As Total

From Info

Join 
    (Select TrackingNumber 
     From Info 
     Where Carrier = 'UPS' And Errored = 0
     Group By TrackingNumber HAVING Count(*) = 1) As A

On Info.TrackingNumber = A.TrackingNumber

Where Info.ProcessDateTime>{ts '2013-05-22 00:00:00'} And 
      Info.ProcessDateTime<{ts '2013-05-23 00:00:00'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Sum( NoBoxes )
From Info As I
Where Carrier = 'UPS'
    And ProcessDateTime >= '2013-05-22 00:00:00'
    And ProcessDateTime < '2013-05-23 00:00:00'
    And Errored = 0
    And Voided = 0
    And Not Exists  (
                    Select 1
                    From Info As I1
                    Where I1.TrackingNumber = I.TrackingNumber
                        And Voided <> 0                         
                    )
```

One item I noted is that the date ranges in your sample queries do not overlap with the sample data you provided. Below is a link to the SQL Fiddle version. You did not specify the database and version so I used SQL Server, however the above solution should work in pretty much all database products.

[SQL Fiddle version](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc21b/15)

Comment: This still added the `2` for the "Voided" shipment

Comment: @user2140261 - Huh? I excluded voided.

Comment: But the voids are not on the same line as the original, when a void is created a new row is also created that has the same tracking number. If you exclude the rows with void = 1 then there will be no way to remove the original Row containing that trackingnumber.

Comment: The VERY first row in my sample data has 2 box count, and a void 0, but the second line is the indicating line that the first line is not to be counted based on it having a void <> 0 and the same tracking number

Comment: @user2140261 - This is a change in logic. Are you saying that if a tracking number is associated with a row where `Void <> 0`, that the tracking number and any other rows associated with that tracking number should be excluded? Is that true for rows where `Errored <> 0`?

Comment: @user2140261 - Also, what is the primary key of the table?

Comment: @user2140261 - Also, why the `Count(*) = 1`? I.e., is it possible to have two rows with the same tracking number where `Errored = 0` and `Voided = 0` for both rows? Is it possible for that to occur on the same day?

Comment: I apologize if this was unclear that is why I included my efforts at this in the question, if you note the first Attempt I made i would like to filter all records `WHERE ((Carrier='UPS') AND (Errored=0))` And ProcessDateTime between my date range then out of the result, Leave only rows having TrackingNumber Count = 1. They Key would be a column called `ID`

Comment: The ONLY time a trackingnumber will have a count > 1 is when it is voided, thus I don't want these included in the SUM. Also all `Errored = 1` will have a blank trackingnumber.

Comment: @user2140261 - I've revised my solution to switch to an Exists clause.

Comment: @user2140261 - Ok. So you want to exclude tracking numbers where there exists a voided row. Think this last update should have it.

Comment: The update still returned `26` when it should return `24`, 24 being the sum of (from my sample data) Rows{4,5,10,11} whose `NoBoxes` values are {7,1,7,9}

Comment: @user2140261 - Check the latest revision and SQL Fiddle results. It returns 24

Comment: Haha, it works I also created my own answer to this question that worked, It seems I had all the right pieces as stated in my Question I just had to figure out how to put them together! According to Fiddle though mine has an execution time of 3ms, while yours has 0ms, Would if be possible for you to explain why yours is better and how it works please? [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/835a6/23/0) is the link to my Fiddle Version.

Comment: @user2140261 - With so little data, there shouldn't be such a significant difference in execution time. So, in part I suspect that issue is SqlFiddle itself. That said, there is only a single row where `Voided=1` so the Exists clause is very quick. Depending on your DBMS, DBMS version, indexes, load, amount of data etc. that equation might change.

Comment: @user2140261 - Actually, as I look at your query, one significant difference is that you are using a derived table. That effectively requires the execution engine to scan through the rows twice. That might be the difference in execution time.

Comment: Testing on my Actual Table 10 times using my statement, and then 10 times using yours, the Averages are Mine = 187ms and Yours = 196ms. So not really much change one way or the other it seems.Is there any reason why one SHOULD use your method as opposed to mine?

Comment: @user2140261 - Again, it depends on indexes, amount of data, cardinality on voided shipments, DBMS, DMBS version... Without looking at the read/write statistics and execution plans between the two based on real data, there is no way to say definitively that one will perform better than the other.

Comment: I apologize if it feels like I am being repetitive with this I am just trying to learn the optimization process as I do not have any administrative experience with DB's. So in this case it is MSSql '08, No indexes, the list will grow about 650 Rows a day. and will have a 2-5% rate of Void rows. In this situation what would be more optimal or how would i go about optimizing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to include a check for `ProcessDateTime = NULL` in your first query:

```
SELECT Sum(NoBoxes)
FROM Info
WHERE (Carrier='UPS') AND
      ((ProcessDateTime>{ts '2013-05-23 00:00:00'} And ProcessDateTime<{ts '2013-05-24 00:00:00'}) or
       ProcessDateTime is NULL
      ) AND
      (IsError=0)
GROUP BY TrackingNumber
HAVING (Count(*)=1)
```

If you want the overall sum, then make this a subquery and sum the values from that.

Comment: This would leave the nulls in the final count if the matching row is not in that date range.

Answer (score 0):

Here is everything.  First part is what I created to test.  Second part is what you need

```
DECLARE @Info TABLE
(
    NoBoxes int,
    Carrier varchar(50),
    ProcessDateTime DateTime,
    Errored int,
    Voided int,
    TrackingNumber varchar(100)
)

Insert into @Info (NoBoxes, Carrier, ProcessDateTime, Errored, Voided, TrackingNumber) Values ( 2, 'UPS', '2013-05-22 8:14', 0, 0, '1Z1234567891234567')
Insert into @Info (NoBoxes, Carrier, ProcessDateTime, Errored, Voided, TrackingNumber) Values ( NULL, 'UPS', NULL, 0, 1, '1Z1234567891234567')
Insert into @Info (NoBoxes, Carrier, ProcessDateTime, Errored, Voided, TrackingNumber) Values ( 5, 'UPS', '2013-05-22 8:22', 1, 0, NULL)
Insert into @Info (NoBoxes, Carrier, ProcessDateTime, Errored, Voided, TrackingNumber) Values ( 7, 'UPS', '2013-05-22 8:14', 0, 0, '1Z9876543210987654')
Insert into @Info (NoBoxes, Carrier, ProcessDateTime, Errored, Voided, TrackingNumber) Values ( 1, 'UPS', '2013-05-22 8:22', 0, 0, '1Z1472583691472583')
Insert into @Info (NoBoxes, Carrier, ProcessDateTime, Errored, Voided, TrackingNumber) Values ( 1, 'FedEx', '2013-05-22 8:14', 0, 0, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
Insert into @Info (NoBoxes, Carrier, ProcessDateTime, Errored, Voided, TrackingNumber) Values ( 8, 'FedEx', '2013-05-22 8:22', 0, 0, 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy')
Insert into @Info (NoBoxes, Carrier, ProcessDateTime, Errored, Voided, TrackingNumber) Values ( 3, 'USPS', '2013-05-22 8:14', 0, 0, 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz')
Insert into @Info (NoBoxes, Carrier, ProcessDateTime, Errored, Voided, TrackingNumber) Values ( 4, 'USPS', '2013-05-22 8:22', 0, 0, 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
Insert into @Info (NoBoxes, Carrier, ProcessDateTime, Errored, Voided, TrackingNumber) Values ( 7, 'UPS', '2013-05-22 8:14', 0, 0, '1Z9638527411012396')
Insert into @Info (NoBoxes, Carrier, ProcessDateTime, Errored, Voided, TrackingNumber) Values ( 9, 'UPS', '2013-05-22 8:22', 0, 0, '1Z4561591981655445')




;
```

I would definitely use a CTE

```
WITH FIRSTCTE (TrackingNumber)
AS
(
    Select TrackingNumber 
    From @Info 
    Where Carrier = 'UPS' And Errored = 0
    Group By TrackingNumber
)
select *
FROM FIRSTCTE as C
    INNER JOIN @Info as I
        ON I.TrackingNumber = C.TrackingNumber
WHERE DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, I.ProcessDateTime)) = '2013-05-22'
```

Comment: This does not return the sum, it also did not eliminate the first row from my sample as it should have, because the tracking number has a count of 2.